# Insert if nothing exists

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to insert rows if nothing exists in a table.

Something like that:

```
WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Students) THEN
INSERT INTO Students (name) VALUES ("Foo Bar"), ("Bar Foo")
```

But it causes `Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "WHEN": syntax error`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use:

```
INSERT INTO Students (name) 
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ("Foo Bar"), ("Bar Foo"))
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Students);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=c6b2fc16c17e76484aa0392a9bcae811)**